# Jfrog Artifactory REST API Documentation

Tags: rest, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm running JFrog Artifactory 7.77.6 rev 77706900 (Self Hosted JFROG PLATFORM).
All the documentation about rest API refer to using 8080 port which is not being used in the new version anymore.
You can see an updated list of used ports here (as I said 8080 is omitted here):

`https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/artifactory-network-ports`

Now I have a critical requirement to stop all running tasks as documented here:

`https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/stop-all-tasks`

But none of the explanations help.

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: If there is something like swagger support in JFrog, that might answer my requirement.

Comment: Are you referring to Artifactory or Distribution? This page refers to Distribution, which is different than Artifactory.

Comment: I'm using JFrog Platform.

Comment: The JFrog platform is made up of multiple products and services. So the first page you noted is artifactory only. The API you mentioned is of Distribution, and it's documented in https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/distribution-network-ports. The docs need to be improved.